# Does Liquid block explorer omits range proofs?

Tags: liquid, confidential-transactions, blockchain-explorer

I am looking at a random Liquid TX like [this one](https://blockstream.info/liquid/tx/906797b3220ce76ebfe1ded17c36a6888edb87e8f60845a456ccae1dea415dfe). It is a CT with the total size of 9205 bytes. Am I correct to assume that the bulk of the total size are range proofs, but they are not shown in the explorer (probably for readability reasons)? What is the best way to actually see them otherwise?